# Why do big-O terms disappear in definite integrals since Mathematica 9?

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion, implementation-details

In Mathematica 8, when I computed the following input:

```
Integrate[Series[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2}], {x, 0, a}]
```

Mathematica returned an expression that had a O[a^4] in it. (In other words, the result had the head `SeriesData`.)

Since Mathematica 9, the same input returns the result without the Big-O term, as if it had internally called `Normal` before or after calculating the integral.

Note that this only happens when I compute definite integrals.

My old code doesn't compute anymore! Is there a way to get back to the Mathematica 8 behaviour?

I assume Wolfram Research had a good reason for this change. Are there any dangers associated with definite integrals of `SeriesData` objects?

Comment: I will add that it doesn't just tack `Normal` on there -- at least, not literally in the sense that the new `Integrate[]` is the old `Integrate[Normal[]]`. Try integrating a `SparseArray` object, you get a sparse array back (although it has been integrated appropriately).

Comment: It's now item `n+1` on my list of things to look into. Alas, `n` is, like Buzz Lightyear, somewhere beyond infinity.

Comment: According the Trace log, it seems the correct indefinite integral result (`SeriesData[x, 0, {1, 0, -1/6}, 1, 4, 1]`) is correctly found during calculation. But for some mysterious reason `a - a^3 / 6` suddenly jumps out...

Answer (score 1):

```
 SeriesData[ a , 0 , #, 0, Length@#, 1] &@CoefficientList[#, a] &@
   Integrate[Series[Cos[x], {x, 0, 3}], {x, 0, a}]
```

> [image]

second try:

```
 int = (SeriesData[a, 0, #[[1]], 0, #[[2]] + 1, 1] &@
         {CoefficientList[Integrate[ Normal@# , {x, 0, a }] , a], #[[5]] }) &;

 int@Series[Cos[x], {x, 0, 3}]
```

> [image]

```
 int@Series[x^4, {x, 0, 3}]
```

> [image]

Now after working that out the hard way I wonder why you don't just use the indefinite integral.

Comment: If the (integrated) series has a term `a^n`, your code just slaps an `O[a]^n+1` onto it. This is wrong, for instance when integrating `Series[x^4, {x, 0, 3}]`: Your code gives `O[a]^0` when it should give `O[a]^5`.

Comment: good call, see edit..